# Use paste within lm to conserve variable names

Tags: r, lm

I am doing **several** linear regressions and I am looping through the variables that I want to use in the model. I want to present the output from R and I want my variables names to appear in the summary of lm.

If I have:

```
var1 <- "nice_name_var1"
var2 <- "nice_name_var2"
depvar <- "nice_name_dep_var"
```

That I know are present in my data frame `my.df`

I cannot do this:

```
lm(paste(depvar,sep="") ~ paste(var1,sep="") + paste(var2,sep=""),
data=my.df)
```

I know that I could do this, and this works, but then the `summary` output doesn't have the names of the variables that I want:

```
lm(my.df[,paste(depvar,sep="")] ~ my.df[,paste(var1,sep="")] + my.df[,paste(var2,sep="")])
data=my.df)
```

Comment: not very clear but maybe `broom` package could be helpful... i.e. `tidy(summary(lm(.....)))`

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that when you use `summary` you get the name of the coefficients. In the second case the name of the coefficients will be just: `my.df[,paste(depvar,sep="")]` which are not what I want.

Comment: Just checked `tidy`, since I get a dataframe I can change the name of the rows/cols now. Thanks!

Comment: Would it be easier to convert a string to a formula, i.e. `as.formula(sprintf(%s ~ %s + %s, depvar, var1, var2))`.  This would result in the actual variable names being used so you wouldn't have to rename the terms in the `tidy` output.

Comment: You should look into `reformulate`. It will do what you want in a much more logical way. Something like `reformulate(c(var1, var2), depvar)` will give you the formula, then `lm(reformulate(c(var1, var2), depvar), data=my.df)` will run the regression.

Comment: I was going to suggest `broom` but Sotos beat me to it. It's useful to learn both `broom` and `modelr` if you're trying to do complex things with regressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) paste** Using the built in `anscombe` data frame as an example:

```
depvar <- "y1"
var1 <- "x1"
var2 <- "x2"

fo <- as.formula(paste(depvar, "~", var1, "+", var2))
do.call("lm", list(fo, quote(anscombe)))
```

giving this output which does show the variable names `x1`, `x2` and `y1`:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y1 ~ x1 + x2, data = anscombe)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2  
     3.0001       0.5001           NA
```

`lm` will accept a character string in place of a formula so `as.formula` can be omitted if it is ok to have quotes shown around it in the output.

**2) model.frame/terms** Another approach is:

```
mf <- model.frame(anscombe[c(depvar, var1, var2)])
do.call("lm", list(terms(mf), quote(anscombe)))
```

giving similar output.